# Markup Validation error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, syntax-error, markup

**I am getting this error in my markup validation:**

Warning Line 23, Column 23: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

**Is there something wrong with the "<" character in the following js?**

```
function preloadImages(array) {
if (!preloadImages.list) {
    preloadImages.list = [];
}
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = array[i];
    preloadImages.list.push(img);
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty standard `for` loop to me

Comment: You probably have this inlined in a XHTML document.

Comment: Markup validation? Do you mean HTML?

Comment: OTOH, the `<` in your snippet isn't on line 23, so there's obviously some additional code that isn't included.

Comment: the problem is not in your syntax, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I still say that he is probably validating against XHTML and has this Javascript inlined in the document without CDATA block…

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `<` in your JavaScript.  But, JavaScript is not "markup".

Comment: Enclose your JS within comment tags to avoid validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your document is XHTML and your Javascript is inlined. At least you seem to be validating against XHTML. Since XHTML is rather strict and closer to XML, `<` is interpreted as the start of a new tag and confused the validator.

There is a number of ways to fix this:

- Use HTML5 instead of XHTML; really, this usually is the best choice unless you have a good reason to stick to XHTML. It is understood by all major browsers and is the latest and most modern doctype that allows all the cool new features of the Web 2.0. The doctype for HTML5 looks like this:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  ....
  ```
- Don't inline your Javascript, but add it as an external resource. You should be doing this all the time anyway, no matter what doctype you are using:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
  ```
- Enclose the script in a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
      // your code
  ]]>
  </script>
  ```

You can read up on [doctypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) and [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) for further details.

Comment: thank you ingo. yes, it is an xhtml doc but the script is in the head.  I have 2 other js scripts in the head that don't cause an error.

Comment: They won't if they're not using XML entities such as `<`, `>` or `&`. Just do any of the methods I mentioned to get rid of the error.

Comment: the site was originally a wordpress site that was converted to html and I just never bothered to update the doctype that wordpress used.  I will be using <!DOCTYPE html> from now on